# Configurable @SerializedName in Gson

Tags: java, gson

Could I get `@SerializedName` value from config file etc.?

I mean like:

```java
@SerializedName(value = configProfider.getJsonFieldName())
private String myField
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was particularly wrong in my comment: this is possible in Gson, but not with `@SerializedName` (due to how Gson works internally) and non-compile time expressions (due to Java restrictions). Sorry for the confusion. Gson supports a custom field naming strategy that you can supply while configuring your `Gson` instance.

Consider the following custom annotation:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
@interface DynamicSerializedName {

    String value();

}
```

Now just implement your strategy:

```java
final class DynamicSerializedNameStrategy
        implements FieldNamingStrategy {

    private final Function<? super String, String> translator;

    private DynamicSerializedNameStrategy(final Function<? super String, String> translator) {
        this.translator = translator;
    }

    static FieldNamingStrategy getDynamicSerializedNameStrategy(final Function<? super String, String> translator) {
        return new DynamicSerializedNameStrategy(translator);
    }

    @Override
    public String translateName(final Field field) {
        final DynamicSerializedName annotation = field.getAnnotation(DynamicSerializedName.class);
        if ( annotation == null ) {
            // Taking the default naming strategy
            // @SerializedName takes higher priority in ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter anyway
            return FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY.translateName(field);
        }
        final String key = annotation.value();
        final String resolvedName = translator.apply(key);
        if ( resolvedName == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot resolve name by " + key + " for " + field);
        }
        return resolvedName;
    }

}
```

Create an annotation:

```java
final class Model {

    @DynamicSerializedName("gson.model.field")
    final String field = null;

}
```

How it can be used (system properties-based example):

```
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingStrategy(getDynamicSerializedNameStrategy(System::getProperty))
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43517297.class, "arbitrary.json") ) {
        final Model model = gson.fromJson(reader, Model.class);
        System.out.println(model.field);
    }
}
```

This example will fail unless you do:

- either define the `gson.model.field` system property programmatically like `System.setProperty("gson.model.field", "dynamic");`;
- or define the system property using the `-D` parameter while starting the JVM: `-Dgson.model.field=dynamic`.

Consider the following JSON (referenced as `arbitrary.json` above):

```
{
    "static": "BY-STATIC-NAME",
    "dynamic": "BY-DYNAMIC-NAME"
}
```

Once the `@DynamicSerializedName` annotation is set and the corresponding property is properly configured the output will be:

> BY-DYNAMIC-NAME

Once you remove the `@DynamicSerializedName` annotation from the DTO field, or annotate the field with `@SerializedName` (it has higher priority as of Gson 2.8.0), the output will be:

> BY-STATIC-NAME